# Ошибка запуска nodejs скрипта на heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

При попытке запуска скрипта на heroku, получаю ошибку:

```
2021-07-05T21:22:30.449963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-07-05T21:22:32.504688+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T21:22:32.504712+00:00 app[web.1]: > vk-app@1.0.0 start /app
2021-07-05T21:22:32.504713+00:00 app[web.1]: > cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=true react-scripts start
2021-07-05T21:22:32.504713+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T21:22:32.513458+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: cross-env: not found
2021-07-05T21:22:32.519970+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-07-05T21:22:32.520339+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-07-05T21:22:32.520509+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-07-05T21:22:32.520767+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-07-05T21:22:32.524935+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! vk-app@1.0.0 start: `cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=true react-scripts start`
2021-07-05T21:22:32.525095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-07-05T21:22:32.525252+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-07-05T21:22:32.525392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the vk-app@1.0.0 start script.
2021-07-05T21:22:32.525503+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-07-05T21:22:32.533747+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T21:22:32.533935+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-07-05T21:22:32.533938+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-07-05T21_22_32_527Z-debug.log
2021-07-05T21:22:32.588416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-05T21:22:33.175940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

> packages.json

```
{
  "name": "vk-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "vk-miniapps-deploy"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vkontakte/icons": "^1.92.0",
    "@vkontakte/vk-bridge": "^2.4.2",
    "@vkontakte/vk-miniapps-deploy": "0.0.25",
    "@vkontakte/vkjs": "^0.21.0",
    "@vkontakte/vkui": "^4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "eruda": "^2.4.1",
    "eruda-code": "^2.0.0",
    "eruda-dom": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Я как понял не найден cross-env, но почему если он указан в packages, и была выполнена установка npm install в папке с проектом, как можно это пофиксить?

Comment: Перенести его в dependencies

Comment: И почитать чем отличается dependencies от devDependencies. В частности babel-eslint нужно бы наоборот перенести